# List of contributions by the users listed in a specific category in MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki

With [Wikiscan](http://wikiscan.org/?menu=userstats&userlist=Cat%C3%A9gorie%3AFormation+Afrip%C3%A9dia+Madagascar) I can see stats of users whose userpage is listed in a specific category.

How can I see all contributions by [Wikipedia users in a specific category](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat%C3%A9gorie:Formation_Afrip%C3%A9dia_Madagascar)? The category only contains their user pages.

Answer (score 2):

You want the Special:Contributions list for *users* listed in that category. And indeed this is not something MediaWiki core offers. There is however a tool by Magnus Manske, **Herding sheep**, which produces [list of edits by a list of users](https://tools.wmflabs.org/magnustools/herding_sheep.php?language=fr&project=wikipedia&category=Formation+Afrip%C3%A9dia+Madagascar&users=&timestamp_stop=&timestamp=&limit=500&doit=Do+it).

The toolbox item "Related changes" lists all [recent changes to pages in the category](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sp%C3%A9cial:Suivi_des_liens/Cat%C3%A9gorie:Formation_Afrip%C3%A9dia_Madagascar) (it's provided by MediaWiki core).

EducationProgram users [have a tool](https://tools.wmflabs.org/coursestats/) (down right now) which is not particularly pretty but does the job for them. Others use [WikiMetrics](http://metrics.wmflabs.org/) which however produces only grand totals.

Comment: This is only giving me a list of the changes of user pages, not a list of contributions of users in the categories.

Comment: @KasperSouren, ah you are right, I misunderstood what the category contained. Let me edit the answer (it may be deleted, I guess, but then we'd lose this conversation).